# Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type int256

Tags: solidity, error, compiler

I'm trying to compile the following keep getting an error, even though used this before in second code and its working fine.
Simply trying to change the temp to the new temperature set by the user, so that I could call/get it from Solidity.
Any help on how to fix the error or achieve what I want?

Code:

```
uint256 public temp;
constructor() public payable {
.
.
.
.
  temp = 15;
    }
event DataCommited( int256 T, string _L);

function commitTask(int256 _temp, string memory _location) public inState(State.Created) payable{
require (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(location)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_location)));
require(_temp < 35 && _temp > -5, "Temperature out of range");
dataCount += 1;

if(dataCount == rewardNum)
        {
            msg.sender.transfer(reward);
            emit TaskDone();
        }

        emit DataCommited( _temp, _location);
        _temp = temp;

    }
```

Working code without an error:

```
uint256 age;
function setInstructor(string memory _fName, uint256 _age) onlyOwner public  {
   fName = _fName;
   age = _age;
   emit Instructor (_fName, _age);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `uint256 temp` and `int256 _temp`.

In `_temp = temp`, you are trying to assign the value of a `uint256` variable to an `int256` variable.

The compilation error tells you that you cannot use an implicit conversion, so use an explicit conversion instead:

```
_temp = int256(temp);
```

Comment: Ohh thanks, you're a life saver.

Comment: Any ideas why in the working code I didnt get that error though?

Comment: @user51821: In the working code, both `age` and `_age` are of the same type (`uint256`).

Comment: Ohh yes, I didnt notice that. Though all along both we're same type.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because you define `int256` datatype for the first argument in event `DataCommited` and you are passing `temp` that is the type of `uint256`.